# Class 'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider' not found when installing

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5.1

I'm using [LaravelStapler](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/laravel-stapler) package to manage image in Laravel 5.1.

I installed LaravelStapler with the following steps:

1. Add  `"codesleeve/laravel-stapler": "^1.0"` into composer.json file
2. Add  `'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider'` into providers array  in `config/app.php` file
3. Run `composer install`

And faced the error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider' not found

If i run composer install before  add `'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider'` into providers array  in `config/app.php` file, no error occurs.

It's  hard for me to deploy into productions when I need to comment out `'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider'` before `composer install` and uncomment after in production.

Are there any solutions which I can install it without commenting out `'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider'` ?

Thanks in advance !

**Update:**

Sorry, It's my mistake. My team mate ignored composer.lock in Repository. I reviewed his pull-request and didn't realize that. Everything works as normal.

Comment: Do not 'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider' put this in app.php file before performing the composer install or update command. First add entry in composer.json then perfrom install or update and after this you have to register the service provider in app.php

Comment: @AlankarMore yes, but for deployment into production, my source code has  'Codesleeve\LaravelStapler\Providers\L5ServiceProvider' in app.php before performing the composer install command. So if I want to deploy my app, I need to comment out it from app.php before  `composer install` and add it again in production ?

Comment: Yes for production you have to comment that part and then execute composer install and after that again remove the comment from app.php file.

Comment: it's hard for me to do like that

Comment: How you are maintaining your code I mean which service you are using. SVN , GIT ?

Comment: I'm using git, and Envoy to deploy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103703/discussion-between-alankar-more-and-chung).